# how to mute sound in flash as2

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript-2, timeline

I want to mute the sound not pause....i already using **setVolume** script on other buttons.
If their is any other option for mute please let me  know..

Answer (score 0):

in `AS2` try `stopAllSounds()` or create a global `Sound()` object to control the global volume.

Check this: http://www.quip.net/blog/2006/flash/how-to-toggle-sound-globally

Ciao!

Comment: Anyway, if you're starting with Flash and ActionScript, I strongly suggest to start with AS3. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html